# Error after hosting to hostgator

Tags: cpanel, web-hosting

i am trying to deploy my website on this link : [http://face-architects.com](http://face-architects.com/)

but the problem i am facing is this. you can see in above link for my domain  at the end of this report for WWW option. It is redirecting to somewhere here:

```
www.face-architects.com -> ghs.google.com -> ghs.l.google.com -> [ 74.125.206.121  ]
```

i don't what is this happening with me. i have uploaded many sited in different server. but i haven't faced such kind of problems so far.

[http://www.intodns.com/face-architects.com](http://intodns.com/face-architects.com)

please provide proper solution.
this website is hosted on hostgator. it gives google's 404 error.

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go to Myaccount for your domain from wherever you bought your domain.

Then select manage DNS=> then go to Zone settings and change

WWW which points to [ghs.google.com](http://ghs.google.com)

Replace with 
[face-architects.com](http://face-architects.com)

and You are done.

Please do comments.

Comment: thanks brother... i have been looking for this solution since last 5 days... got success.